# Java method to add daily interest to bank account after month is over

Tags: java, finance

For an assignment, I am told to write two methods: `incrementDay()` and `incrementMonth()`:

> **`incrementDay()`**
>
> This method takes no input and returns nothing. If the previous
>   month's balance was not paid in full, the credit card charges interest
>   on the current balance after each day. To do this, the class will need
>   two additional fields, a variable that keeps track of the interest
>   charged so far and a `boolean` variable that is a paid-in-full flag that
>   keeps track of whether the user has paid the balance in full.
>
> `incrementDay` works as follows: If the paid-in-full flag is false then
>   sum the account balance and the interest charged so far, then multiply
>   this sum by the interest rate divided by 365, and add this value to
>   the interest charged so far.
>
> If the paid-in-full flag is true, then there is nothing to do.
>
> **`incrementMonth()`**
>
> This method takes no input and returns nothing. Add the interest
>   charged so far to the account balance. Reset the interest charged so
>   far to 0.
>
> If the total payment this month is greater than or equal to the
>   monthly payment, set the paid-in-full flag to true, otherwise set the
>   flag to false.
>
> If the minimum monthly payment is smaller than the monthly payment and
>   the total payment this month is less than the minimum monthly payment,
>   add the late payment penalty to the current balance.
>
> Set the total payment this month to 0.
>
> Set the monthly payment equal to the current balance.

I'm just asking for someone to read my code and tell me if the logic and tests work in all cases.

```
public void incrementDay()
  {
    if(!paidInFullFlag)
    {
      interestCharged += (this.balance + interestCharged) * (interestRate/365);
    }
  }

  /*Method adds interestCharged to balance and checks whether or not account has been paid in full for month*/
  public void incrementMonth()
  {
    this.balance += interestCharged;
    this.interestCharged = 0;
    if(this.sumPayment >= this.monthlyPayment)
    {
      this.paidInFullFlag = true;
    }
    else 
    {
      this.paidInFullFlag = false;
    }

    if(minMonthly < monthlyPayment && sumPayment < minMonthly)
    {
      this.balance += latePaymentPenalty;
    }
    this.sumPayment = 0;
    this.monthlyPayment = this.balance;
  }
```

**Test:**

```
> CreditCardAccount c = new CreditCardAccount()
> c.setCreditLimit(100)
> c.setInterestRate(.08)
> c.setLatePaymentPenalty(3)
> c.setMinMonthlyPayment(20)
> c.charge(30)
true
> c.getBalance()
30.0
> c.payment(5) //pay 5 dollars towards balance
> c.incrementDay() 
> c.incrementMonth()
> c.getBalance() //flag is initially set to true, so no late payment penalty or interest is charged, but flag is set to false for next month
25.0
> c.payment(5)
> c.charge(20)
true
> c.getBalance()
40.0
> c.incrementMonth() //late payment penalty is charged
> c.getBalance() 
43.0
> c.incrementDay()
> c.getBalance()
43.0
> c.incrementMonth()
> c.getBalance() //interest AND late payment penalty is added
46.00942465753425
```

Answer (score 1):

### Conventions

Java conventions state that code is indented with 4 spaces, not 2. Java also states that the brace should be on the same line, though this is more of your choice; the important part is consistency. After formatting, your code will then look like:

```
public void incrementDay() {
    if (!paidInFullFlag) {
        interestCharged += (this.balance + interestCharged) * (interestRate
                / 365);
    }
}

/*
 * Method adds interestCharged to balance and checks whether or not account
 * has been paid in full for month
 */
public void incrementMonth() {
    this.balance += interestCharged;
    this.interestCharged = 0;
    if (this.sumPayment >= this.monthlyPayment) {
        this.paidInFullFlag = true;
    } else {
        this.paidInFullFlag = false;
    }

    if (minMonthly < monthlyPayment && sumPayment < minMonthly) {
        this.balance += latePaymentPenalty;
    }
    this.sumPayment = 0;
    this.monthlyPayment = this.balance;
}
```

### Miscellaneous

Here:

```
    if (this.sumPayment >= this.monthlyPayment) {
        this.paidInFullFlag = true;
    } else {
        this.paidInFullFlag = false;
    }
```

Since the condition is a boolean already, this could be simplified to:

```
    this.paidInFullFlag = this.sumPayment >= this.monthlyPayment;
```

---

The comment here:

```
/*
 * Method adds interestCharged to balance and checks whether or not account
 * has been paid in full for month
 */
```

Should be a JavaDoc comment:

```
/**
 * Method adds interestCharged to balance and checks whether or not account
 * has been paid in full for month
 */
```

Very similar, but not exactly the same.